# SQL Server execution XML plan cut off in length

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, xml

I am running the following standard query to retrieve the XML execution plan for queries that I ran on my SQL Server via command line.

`SELECT pl.query_plan FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ep CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ep.plan_handle) pl;`

However, it seems that for all the query plans, they are cut off partially. It's as if each row of the result is displaying only a certain number of characters. Is there some setting I need to enable to be able to see the full XML in each row?

Comment: Telling us exactly how many characters are output, e.g., 1023, 32767, 1048575, or something else, might give us a clue as to where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SSMS, it limits the Grid result set size for both XML and non-XML. You can change the setting here.

[image: SSMS Settings]

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using the command line and want to get all of these XMLs out for further data analysis.

Comment: If by command line you mean SQLCMD then you might be interested in this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548315/4609186